# Computer calculations in A_infinity categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-science, mathematical-software

> Is there a *good* computer program for doing calculations in A-infinity categories?

Explicit calculations in A-infinity categories are an important, useful, yet very tedious task. One has to keep track of horrific signs and the combinatorics of trees is lurking always in the background. Examples of such calculations include:

1. Minimal A-infinity structures on e.g. Ext-algebras of quiver representations.
2. Morphism spaces between A-infinity modules.
3. Multiplications on twisted complexes.

Doing this explicit calculation is merely a book-keeping problem and therefore calls for some computer support. Is there a good solution for that problem?

At best I would like to have a well documented [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) library - but this is apparently too much to ask. Here are my Google searches results:

- In Paul Seidel's proof of [Mirror Symmetry for the Quartic K3 surface](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310414), he uses a [python script](http://www-math.mit.edu/~seidel/k3/explain.html)  to do calculations in A-infinity categories.
- [Mikael Vejdemo-Johansson](http://math.stanford.edu/~mik/) has written a thesis on Computation of A-inifinity algebras in group cohomology. He gives some code in Haskell,  there is an MAGMA implementation for the A-infinity strucures on group cohomology, [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/904). Thanks to [mt](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6481/mt) for the reference!
- Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen and Samuel Boissier use the  MAUDE  rewriting system to make explicit computation in cohomology rings of the Hilbert-Scheme of points in [Generating series in the cohomology of Hilbert schemes of points on surfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610837). Maybe similar methods have been used for A-infinity calculations?

Comment: I know that Laurent Bartholdi has spent some time making a program that computes minimal A-inf structures on Ext-algebras (mainly in the context of group cohomology). The problem is that this A-inf structure is highly non-unique, and that once you have it in front of you, there are still a bunch of questions that you can't really answer.

Comment: The Magma implementation of $A_\infty$ structures on group cohomology is described in the Magma documentation here http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/904

Comment: Thx @mt for the reference. I have edited the question accordingly.

@Andre, do you know if Laurent Barholdi published his code somewhere? I think that the non-uniqueness makes it even more desireable to not do the computations by hand ;)

Comment: for me the relevant section of Magma handbook is strangely this one: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/937 (the one you link says "Construction of Subalgebras, Ideals and Quotient Rings")

Comment: It seems the Magma handbook is updated in such a way that links are not stable. In the version of the site I see today, labeled "V2.23, 6 July 2017" in the lower right corner, the relevant link is http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/985 . This search link might be more stable: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/search?query=a-infinity&chapters=1&examples=1&intrinsics=1